# Submitting form with photo data using ajax and mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am trying to submit my form using ajax, since when I submit the form the typical way the page reloads and I lose track of what radio buttons are selected.

I've tried a few methods, but this one seems to be the most promising. I serialize the data from the form when I grab the element using JQuery, then send a post to my controller, however the ImageFile I upload always returns null when I use this method, any help would be much appreciated!

Photo Class:

```
namespace MVCEventCalendar
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Photo
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string SubEvent { get; set; }
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddInspectionPhoto(Photo imagemodel)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagemodel.ImageFile.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(imagemodel.ImageFile.FileName);
    fileName = fileName + "_" + imagemodel.EventID + "_" + imagemodel.SubEvent;
    imagemodel.Path = "../InspectionPhotos/" + fileName + "." +extension;
    fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../InspectionPhotos/"), fileName + extension);
    imagemodel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

    using (InspectionPhotoEntities db = new InspectionPhotoEntities())
    {
        imagemodel.EventID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Event"].ToString());
        imagemodel.SubEvent = "GC1";
        db.Photos.Add(imagemodel);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    //ModelState.Clear();
    var status = true;
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    //return View("~/Views/Home/InspectionChecklist.cshtml");
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle">Upload a Photo!</span></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddInspectionPhoto" method="post" id="photoform" role="form">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <input type="file" name="ImageFile" id="imageFile" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">
                                    <button type="button" style="background-color: #454545; color: #ffffff;" class="btn btn-default" id="submitPhoto">Submit Photo</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
        $('body').on('click', '#submitPhoto', function () {

            //var filePath = $('#imageFile').filePath;

            //var imageJSON = {
            //    SubEvent: SubEvent,
            //    ImageFile: filePath
            //}


            //UploadPhoto(imageJSON);
            console.log("submittingform");
                var $form = $('photoform');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/home/AddInspectionPhoto',
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        //do something about the error
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //do something with response
                        //LoadBooks();
                        console.log("DONEEEE");
                    }
                });

                return false;// if it's a link to prevent post



        });
```

There must be something I'm missing here, could it be something with serializing the data or the way I send the Photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize()` doesn't work with file inputs you need to use a FormData object and stop jQuery.ajax from setting the content type and processing the data you pass

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/AddInspectionPhoto',
                data: new FormData($form[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //do something about the error
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    //do something with response
                    //LoadBooks();
                    console.log("DONEEEE");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Trying it out now :D